# ConEmu Create new console

Tags: windows, conemu

On starting ConEmu I want PowerShell to be loaded as the default console and also I want it be displayed first in the dropdown list when creating a new console window. How do I do that?

Comment: this question better fit on superuser. i've this line in the startup/command line option of conEmu : `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -new_console:a`

Comment: Moreover there is already similar question http://superuser.com/a/786784/139371

Comment: I tried your way @Kayasax and it didnt work for me.
I initially wanted to add a comment on superuser and I have to have 50 reputations before I can. The comment would have been that I must have a different version of ConEmu since there is no such option as "Specified named task".

Comment: @user3294171, at least, you may reveal your exact ConEmu version.

Comment: Would it be 140812.7z ?